# JQuery - Update variable when another variable updates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two variables, one of which is dependent on the other one. See the following.

**This variable is an equation containing other variables:**

```
var startValue = ((serverValue - totalCost) / totalCost ) * 100;
```

**This variable takes the value of the above variable and prints it to div.**

```
var sliderPosition = $("#output").val(startValue.toFixed(1));
```

The issue is that the first variable changes live as a slider is being moved by the user. The second variable needs to update when the first one updates.

Comment: Do you use a javascript library for the slider or do you use the HTML5 slider? If you use a HTML5 slider, you could simply use the .change() function within jquery. If it's a library it probably has an on change listener.

Comment: I'm using the noUiSlider as seen here http://refreshless.com/nouislider/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't exactly do it natively on the fly, but you can definitely have it upload the val on `mouseUp`

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="chance" id="chance" class="text" value="50">
<input type="range" id="slider" class="vHorizon" min="1" max="100" step="1">
```

**JS:**

```
$('#slider').on('change', function(){
    $('#chance').val($('#slider').val());
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tDkEW/54/

Comment: Thanks we ended up realizing we need to restructure everything but the information here was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare `startValue` as global variable;

```
$(function(){
  var startValue;

  //rest of the code
});
```

Comment: I'm assuming you mean that if they are all part of the same function then they will interact the way I wish for them?

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is not possible in javascript to add listener on variable change,
unless you use non standardized apis. See [object.watch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch)

Comment: Assuming he is using jQuery (most likely), there's a plugin called **jQuery Watch** that does this type of things (he could, for example, watch for the `value` attribute): http://darcyclarke.me/dev/watch/

Answer (score 0):

If you use the noUiSlider, check this:

http://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-events

Try using the 'change' event.